# Invalid domain/user/password while installing mongoDB on Windows10

Tags: mongodb

No idea why it is unable to install. I tried my window account the one I use to log in to my PC doesn't work either. So can anyone help me solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Do the accounts you tried have the required permissions? In the screenshot the username is "MangoDB", is that supposed to be correct?

Comment: I tried the account I used to log in to the window, and it gave me the same error. This is just the default setting, and It is not working as well. I checked out a lot video on youtube about how to install mongoDB locally but nothing helps. Now I am using cloud9 IDE with mongoDB installed online. I really want to get it installed locally...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to install it locally do this :

choose run service as local or domain user,
leave the domain user as ".",
write your windows username account in Account name ,
in Account password write your windows account password ,

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.